# Change language ID on URL

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

after hours of searching i cannot find any solution, so I hope someone can help me here.

My problem is that I have to do a webpage on Liferay with the valencian language, there is no problem to add that language to liferay, I have it and works perfectly, the problem is that I have to store that language internally as catalan, to generate the "lang" property on the HTML tag as "ca", for detect the browser language as catalan to load the webpage on that language automatically and to communicate that language with third party portlets, as the Valencian according to the ISO doesn't exist.

The simplest solution is obviously use catalan language and just on the webpage change the flag and the text on the language selector, but if I use that option I have the problem, and is a requeriment by my customer, that in the URL is should show the "va" when the Valencian is selected, and in this scenario the code is "ca". For example "mywebpage/va/home", not "mywebpage/ca/home".

Any ideas how to do this on Liferay?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a step-by-step answer, but here's where you should start looking for it:

Liferay's `WEB-INF/web.xml` contains the following mappings:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>I18n Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.servlet.I18nServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>I18n Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ca/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So you've got the URL mapping handled in [I18nServlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/servlet/I18nServlet.java). Without looking intensely at it, you'll probably have to update it to be aware of your additional language as well.

You may or may not need to do a bit more, in order to introduce a new language to Liferay, but this entry point should help locating the necessary steps. This calls for an ext plugin, but I feel that it could be built quite well-maintainable as it's a quite small change.

Please consider contributing your translation back to Liferay, so that it can be added to the next version (and might be maintained by more people)

Edit: After your comment, a few more thoughts (rather than solid advice)

`I18nServlet` is the key, the source is linked above. I'd recommend to introduce a completely new language, even though VA doesn't have an ISO code: Otherwise you'll have to do all kinds of special handling from/to `va` and `ca`. It might be simple in `I18nServlet`, *resolving* the language from the URL, but the other direction, e.g. Liferay *generating* a URL from a language, typically involves using the language code in the URL.

You can get started with the CA translation, so that the initial work is the same. I feel that it's cleaner this way.

The one reason that might convince me to just map va to ca in the URL, and handle it internally as ca would be if Locale handling, e.g. date- time- and similar formatting would fail with a non-ISO language. Liferay encapsulates at least some of it in LocaleUtil and similar classes, but as I haven't introduced a new language to Liferay yet, I can't give you any recommendation.  This *may or may not* work when you're introducing a variant, e.g. ca_va, where the Locale handling can fall back to ca.

Comment: This step is done to add the Valencian language to my website. 
My problem as I said on the post, is that I need to put on the URL the "va" prefix but internally I have to configure the Catalan language.
So I need how to configure Liferay to use one of these two options:
1- "va" and not "ca" on the URL when the Catalan language is used
2- When Valencian is used, stores internally the "ca" as selected language but mantain the "va" on the URL.

Hope I explained.

Comment: Please refer to my (marked) edit. I seem to have edited early - explained as well what you edited into your comment. I saw your edit only after submitting my edit to the answer.

Comment: Finally as we have forbidden by our customer change the core of Liferay we decided use the Catalan and put manually of each page a friendly urls with path that contains "va" for the Catalan and "es" for the Spanish.
As information, that path of the catalan language can contains "/va/" if is not the first part of the url, for example "www.myweb.com/myserver/va/mypage" and our manually friendly url for the catalan translation of this page is "myserver/va/mypage"
Also, to avoid Liferay to show language on URL automatically, I've configured "locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=0"